# Android Tag permission in applicaiton in Android Manifest?

Tags: android

i have curiosity question.
I seen tag permission in  in Android Manifest
Whatis it used for ?

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        **android:permission=""**
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```